# Generating tree structure for 3D models?

Tags: 3d-model, indexed-3d-scene-layer

I want to create a tool for converting different type of 3D models into [Esri's i3s form](https://github.com/Esri/i3s-spec):

> This repository hosts the specification for Scene Layers which are
>   containers for arbitrarily large amounts of geographic data. The
>   delivery and persistence model for Scene Layers, referred to as
>   Indexed 3d Scene Layer (I3S) and Scene Layer Package (SLPK)
>   respectively, are specified.

To begin with, I'd like to build LOD, or layers for a single model, so
how do I calculate a different level of bounding volume for each part of a model?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Can you provide a link to where you have come across "esri's i3s form", please?  I'm trying to work out which part of the ArcGIS platform you are asking about.

Comment: @PolyGeo please see https://github.com/Esri/i3s-spec
Kartl Tian for general geometries please refer to https://x3dom.org/pop/#References they describe in detail how you can calculate LODs from general geometries.

Comment: @Karl Tian please check out: http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/3DTiles and futhermore https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles/tree/master/specification which should get you started. I don't know how similar 3DTiles and I3S are, but I assume that they are pretty similar.